# Two loan amortisation functions giving different results

Tags: r, finance

I have the following:

```
library(financialMath)

library(reshape2)
library(scales)
################################################################################
mortgage <- function(P = 500000, I = 6, L = 30, amort = TRUE) {
  J <- I / (12 * 100)
  N <- 12 * L
  M <- P * J / (1 - (1 + J)^(-N))
  monthPay <<- M
  # Calculate Amortization for each Month
  if (amort == TRUE) {
    Pt <- P # current principal or amount of the loan
    currP <- NULL
    while (Pt >= 0) {
      H <- Pt * J # this is the current monthly interest
      C <- M - H # this is your monthly payment minus your monthly interest, so it is the amount of principal you pay for that month
      Q <- Pt - C # this is the new balance of your principal of your loan
      Pt <- Q # sets P equal to Q and goes back to step 1. The loop continues until the value Q (and hence P) goes to zero
      currP <- c(currP, Pt)
    }
    monthP <- c(P, currP[1:(length(currP) - 1)]) - currP
    aDFmonth <<- data.frame(
      Month = 1:length(currP),
      Year = sort(rep(1:ceiling(N / 12), 12))[1:length(monthP)],
      Balance = c(currP[1:(length(currP))]),
      Payment = monthP + c((monthPay - monthP)[1:(length(monthP))]),
      Principal = monthP,
      Interest = c((monthPay - monthP)[1:(length(monthP))])
    )
    aDFmonth <<- subset(aDFmonth, Year <= L * 12)
    aDFyear <- data.frame(
      Amortization = tapply(aDFmonth$Balance, aDFmonth$Year, max),
      Annual_Payment = tapply(aDFmonth$Payment, aDFmonth$Year, sum),
      Annual_Principal = tapply(aDFmonth$Principal, aDFmonth$Year, sum),
      Annual_Interest = tapply(aDFmonth$Interest, aDFmonth$Year, sum),
      Year = as.factor(na.omit(unique(aDFmonth$Year)))
    )
    aDFyear <<- aDFyear
  }
  return(aDFmonth)
  # if (plotData == TRUE) {
  #   aDFyear2 <- aDFyear %>%
  #     rename(
  #       Interest = Annual_Interest,
  #       Payment = Annual_Payment,
  #       Principal = Annual_Principal
  #     )
  #   aDFyear2$Year <- as.factor(aDFyear2$Year)
  #   aDFyear2 <- melt(aDFyear2[, c("Interest", "Principal", "Year")], id.vars = "Year")
  #   
  #   ggplot(aDFyear2, aes(x = Year, y = value, fill = variable)) +
  #     geom_bar(position = "fill", stat = "identity") +
  #     labs(y = "Payment") +
  #     scale_y_continuous(labels = percent) +
  #     theme_minimal() +
  #     theme(legend.title = element_blank(), legend.position = "top")
  # }
}

m = mortgage(P = 200000, I = 2, L = 25, amort = TRUE)
m %>% 
  head()

  Month Year  Balance  Payment Principal Interest
1     1    1 199485.6 847.7087  514.3753 333.3333
2     2    1 198970.4 847.7087  515.2326 332.4760
3     3    1 198454.3 847.7087  516.0914 331.6173
4     4    1 197937.3 847.7087  516.9515 330.7572
5     5    1 197419.5 847.7087  517.8131 329.8956
6     6    1 196900.9 847.7087  518.6761 329.0326

amort.table(Loan = 200000, n = 12*25, i = 0.02, pf = 12) %>%
  .[[1]] %>% 
  head()

  Year Payment Interest Paid Principal Paid  Balance
1 0.08  845.95        330.32         515.63 199484.4
2 0.17  845.95        329.46         516.48 198967.9
3 0.25  845.95        328.61         517.34 198450.5
4 0.33  845.95        327.76         518.19 197932.4
5 0.42  845.95        326.90         519.05 197413.3
6 0.50  845.95        326.04         519.90 196893.4
```

The `amort.table()` is taken from the `financialMath` package and the `mortgage` function from here: https://github.com/AntoineSoetewey/mortgage-calculator/blob/master/app.R

I am trying to replicate the mortgage function using the `amort.table()` function but I get slightly different results.

The `payment` and `principal` is only slightly out on both functions but this causes very different results over the whole term of the loan. Looking at the shiny App version here ( https://antoinesoetewey.shinyapps.io/mortgage-calculator/ ) we see the following summary:

```
Summary
Principal (loan amount): 200,000
Annual interest rate: 2%
Term: 25 years (300 months)
Monthly payment: 847.71
Total cost: 200,000 (principal) + 54,312.6 (interest) = 254,312.6
```

However, when I run the following:

```
> amort.table(Loan = 200000, n = 12*25, i = 0.02, pf = 12) %>% 
+   .[[2]]
                       Details
Loan           200000.00000000
Total Paid     253784.16000000
Total Interest  53784.16000000
Eff Rate            0.02000000
i^(12)              0.01981898
```

The total interest paid is out by a $1,000 ( 54,312.6 vs 53,784.16)

How can I make the `amort.table()` function produce the same results as the `mortgage` function?

Comment: I think it's a difference of interest rate definition. I'm not sure about the technical terminology here, but `amort.table` seems to want as input the nominal, compounded interest rate, but it uses the uncompounded rate for each payment. So month 1 pays 1.98% x 1/12 x 200k = $330 in interest, not 2% x 1/12 x 200k = $333. I'm not sure which is more correct for what context. If you enter `i = (1 + 0.02/12)^12`  that might correspond?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We notice `i^(12)` is 0.01981898 in amort.table and this should be 2. This is because the relationship between the effective annual interest rate and monthly interest rate is not simply effective annual interest rate/12 = monthly interest rate.

Replace `i` with the actual interest rate would yield desired results:

```
amort.table(Loan = 200000, n = 12*25, i = (1+0.02/12)^12-1, pf = 12) %>%
  .[[1]] %>%
  head()

  Year Payment Interest Paid Principal Paid  Balance
1 0.08  847.71        333.33         514.38 199485.6
2 0.17  847.71        332.48         515.23 198970.4
3 0.25  847.71        331.62         516.09 198454.3
4 0.33  847.71        330.76         516.95 197937.4
5 0.42  847.71        329.90         517.81 197419.5
6 0.50  847.71        329.03         518.68 196900.9


amort.table(Loan = 200000, n = 12*25, i = (1+0.02/12)^12-1, pf = 12) %>%
  .[[2]]

                    Details
Loan           2.000000e+05
Total Paid     2.543126e+05
Total Interest 5.431260e+04
Eff Rate       2.018436e-02
i^(12)         2.000000e-02
```